# ReactJS: how to access html of rect-element stored in array?

Tags: html, arrays, reactjs, styles, element

In a loop I create a rect-element and push it in an Array:

```
squares = [];
render: function() {
  for (var i = 0 ; i < 10; i++) {
     squares.push (<Rectangle height={this.props.afm} width={this.props.afm} x={xpos} y={ypos} value="3" id="vlakje" name={i} style={{fill: 'rgb('100,100,100')'}} onClick={this.mouseDownEvent} />);
  }
}

var Rectangle = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return <rect width="10"></rect>;
        }
    });
```

Than, when I log the value of for example the first element of the Array, it returns an Object. Later on, I need to access these elements to change the element-style.

When I receive a mouseClick like this:

```
mouseDownEvent: function(ev) {
  var eTarget= ev.target;
}
```

... and I log eTarget, it's gives back a html-tag:

```
<rect width="10" />
```

... which I can access and edit like this:

```
eTarget.style.fill = #ff0000;
```

How do I get this target out of the array so I can change html-style?

Answer (score 0):

If you change `this.mouseDownEvent` to `this.mouseDownEvent.bind(this)`, "`this`" inside the `mouseDownEvent` will reference the Rectangle that was clicked. You can then do whatever to "this" that you like.

Comment: The problem isn't in the mousevent itself, but in the fact that I can't access the html of the objects I stored in the array.

Comment: I want to do like this: squares[2].style.fill = "#ff0000";

Comment: If you want to be able to access the element by array ID, I'd have an array of just data then `map()` it to elements. The point of React is that you aren't manipulating the DOM directly.

Array of data:
`state.squares = [
{fill:"#ff0000"},
{fill:"#00ff00"}
]`

And then in the render function:
`state.squares.map((square)=>{return <rect {other data} fill={square.fill}></rect>})`

And then use setState to trigger to re-rendering of the array:
`squares[2].fill = "#000000";
this.setState(squares: squares);`

Further reading: [https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html]